# Unable to Create MSI Installer File for Outlook Add In

Tags: windows-installer, outlook-addin

I am trying to create an MSI installer file for an Outlook add in which appears to work when run from Visual Studio.

I am using Visual Studio 2015, and Outlook 2013.
The add-in needs to be rolled out to a large number of users, which is why I am trying to build this as an MSI.

So far, I have only been able to create  VSTO or an EXE file, but these fail to update the registry (even though I added this in the Visual Studio setup project).

I have followed the Microsoft white paper on this matter several times now, but all I am getting when I build my solution is an EXE and a VSTO.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on this one - I.e. does anyone have any idea what may be going wrong here?

Any help is much appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to deploy the add-in for all users you need to customize the HKLM hive of the windows registry. To do that you need to have admin privileges. That's why when you run your installer from VS works correctly.

The [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) article in MSDN describes all the required steps for creating MSI installers for Office add-ins in depth.

Comment: Got it in the end by using the mentioned tutorial - thanks!